# Free-Fall time of a collapsing Star (Spherical Symmetry/No Rotation/Classical Mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, stars, free-fall

I have been trying to prove the *free-fall time* $(\tau_\text{ff})$ of a collapsing star, which is the time it would take a star to collapse due to gravity, in the absence of pressure or other supporting forces.

Supposing the density to be constant in a homogeneous spherical non-rotating star, the following well-known result arises:
$$\tau_\text{ff} = \sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{32 \langle\rho\rangle G}}$$
I have tried to derive this relationship, however a factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$ is missing from my result.

My attempt is as follows: consider a particle of mass $m$ at a radius $r$ inside the star; then, its equation of motion, where $M_r$ stands for the mass contained inside the spherical shell of radius $r$, would be:
$$m \frac{\mathrm d^2r}{\mathrm dt^2} = - \frac{G M_r}{r^2} m$$ 
Which is to say:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2r}{\mathrm dt^2} + \frac{G M_r}{r^2} = 0$$

Furthermore, since:
$$\langle\rho\rangle = \frac{M}{\frac{4\pi}{3} R^3}$$
Then:
$$\langle M_r\rangle = 4 \pi \int_{0}^{r} \mathrm dr \> r^2 \langle\rho_r\rangle = \frac{4\pi}{3} \langle\rho\rangle r^3$$
Thus, an order of magnitude approach to the equations of motion would be:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2r}{\mathrm dt^2} + \frac{G \langle M_r\rangle}{r^2} = 0$$
Ergo, the differential equation to solve becomes:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2r}{\mathrm dt^2} + \frac{4\pi}{3} \langle\rho\rangle G \> r = 0 \quad \Big| \quad r(0) = R \> \land \> \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}r(0) = 0$$
Such differential equation has a well-known solution:
$$r(t) = C_1 \> \cos(\alpha t) + C_2 \> \sin(\alpha t) \quad \Big| \quad \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3} \langle\rho\rangle G}$$
Therefore, when imposing the initial conditions, the solution obtained is:
$$r(t) = R \> \cos(\alpha t)$$
Then:
$$r(\tau_\text{ff}) = 0 \Longrightarrow \alpha \tau_\text{ff} = \frac{\pi}{2} \Longrightarrow \tau_\text{ff} = \frac{\pi}{2\alpha} = \sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{16 \langle\rho\rangle G}}$$

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could point out any mistakes in the development. I realize that most proofs derive the result from energy conservation, however I would like to be able to plot the solution to the equations of motion.

Comment: Not sure where you got your first result from, but if you stick numbers for the density of Earth (~5500 kg m$^{-3}$) and $G$ (~6.6$\times 10^{-11}$) into your derived time, you get ~21 minutes, which is the correct amount of time for something to fall from the surface to the centre of the Earth.  That suggests to me your derived time is indeed correct?

Comment: @Garf That isn't the same situation. Here, the mass interior to the particle stays the same throughout its motion. That accounts for the factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You're quite right, I incorrectly envisaged the problem as the density staying constant

Comment: Does not seem like an obvious homework question and there is clear evidence of effort being shown to work through the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a problem with what you have done. In your solution you have made $M_r$ (the sum of mass interior to the radial coordinate of your test mass) a variable that depends on $r$ and hence depends on $t$. But that isn't right; $M_r$ is a constant that should be set equal to the mass interior to an object at the surface of the collapsing star - i.e. the mass of the star - and it is a *constant*.

Thus you need to solve this equation
$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} + \frac{G M}{r^2} = 0$$

This quite messy; for a body with $m\ll M$, falling from radius $R$ to radius $r$, the solution is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body#Examples) as
$$ t = R^{3/2}\left(\frac{ \arccos{(r/R)^{1/2}} + [(r/R)(1 - r/R)]^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2GM}}\right)$$

For the freefall time, set $r=0$ to get
$$ t_{ff} = \frac{\pi R^{3/2}}{2\sqrt{2GM}}$$

Then replace $M$ using $M = 4\pi R^3 \bar{\rho}/3$ and this simplifies to
$$t_{ff} = \sqrt{ \frac{3\pi}{32 G \bar{\rho}}}$$

Note that the freefall time is independent of radius for a homogeneous sphere of gas, so infalling particles do not "overtake" particles that are initially interior to them. This justifies treating $M_r$ as a constant.

Comment: I obviously must have made some error - so whomever downvoted could leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of getting this result is to note that Kepler's law for elliptical motion always takes the form [4(pi)^2]/T^2] = GM/a^3, where a is the semi-major axis. A particle on a sphere surface of radius R would move inward on an ellipse with 2a = R, semi-minor axis = 0. Expressing M in terms of the mean density as M = rho[4(pi)R^3]/3, and keeping in mind that tff = T/2, then returns the well-known result.

Comment: R should be 2a. The orbit is really a line segment with one end at the sphere center and the other at the surface. The period for a full orbit would be T, which in this case corresponds to a particle beginning at R falling to the sphere center and bouncing back to R, hence the in fall time is half that quantity